# Export a table created by HTML aND PHP into an excel file

Tags: php, html, excel

How can I export a table created by PHP into an excel file? Is there any way?

I actually want to do it this way:

Say I am querying the database is a php file and displaying results in a html and PHP table...

This table will be dynamic depending on what the user is searching for. And the users should be able to save the table as a excel file by clicking a EXPORT button...

Is there any option in php to do that?

Comment: You can use php excel for this https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

[PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) is probably the best library to go about doing this with. If you download it, there are a ton of examples that will almost certainly show what you want to do.

A quick example would be the following:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$objWorksheet->fromArray(
    array(
        array('',       'Rainfall (mm)',    'Temperature (°F)', 'Humidity (%)'),
        array('Jan',        78,                 52,                 61),
        array('Feb',        64,                 54,                 62),
        array('Mar',        62,                 57,                 63),
        array('Apr',        21,                 62,                 59),
        array('May',        11,                 75,                 60),
        array('Jun',        1,                  75,                 57),
        array('Jul',        1,                  79,                 56),
        array('Aug',        1,                  79,                 59),
        array('Sep',        10,                 75,                 60),
        array('Oct',        40,                 68,                 63),
        array('Nov',        69,                 62,                 64),
        array('Dec',        89,                 57,                 66),
    )
);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('sheet.xlsx');
```

Alternatively, you could export pretty easily as a [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), which the user could then open in excel without difficulty (not technically an excel document though - there are limitations).

Answer (score 0):

store the table in a varaiable

and write into file

ex:

```
$content = "";//in content you must have table data
$file = fopen("file location", "w");
fwrite($file ,$content);
```

this should help easy

Comment: do you means a sql query in $content ?

Answer (score 0):

If there is an end-user that will view the file use the answer already given using PHPExcel

If your doing it for data-access then use CSV.

https://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

```
$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need formulas or fancy features, it would also be easy to output a CSV file (which Excel can open). If you had an array of arrays like the one enigma demonstrated, you could just use

```
$string = "";
foreach ($array as $row)
    $string .= implode(',', $row) . "\n";
file_put_contents("filename.csv", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a this class. It is able to create multi-sheet excel files from HTML tables.

https://github.com/GSTVAC/HtmlExcel

```
$xls = new HtmlExcel();
$xls->addSheet("Names", $names);
$xls->headers();
echo $xls->buildFile();
```